# How to add indexed objects (indexed with NSMutableIndexSet ) in NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

After indexing an `NSMutableArray` with `NSMutableIndexSet`, I want to add the indexed objects in next `NSMutableArray`. However, the method `objectAtIndexes:(NSIndexset *)indexSet` is defined for NSArray only.

Is there any similar method for `NSMutableArray`?

Here is the code;

```
NSMutableIndexSet *indexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(array.count - 10, array.count)];
myArray = [array objectsAtIndexes:indexSet];
```

Comment: You are clearly wrong. Since `NSMutableArray` is subclassed from `NSArray`, it has `objectAtIndexes:` too.

Comment: The warning says,'Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray*' from 'NSArray*' ' but all my arrays are NSMutableArray.

Comment: Can you paste your code here so we can help you?

Comment: NSMutableIndexSet *indexset = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(array.count-10, array.count)];
myArray = [array objectsAtIndexes:indexset];

Here, 'array' is a NSMutableArray and it's objects are the continuously varying data, 'myArray' is next NSMutableArray which is supposed to store the indexed objects from 'array'.

Comment: I've posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `[NSArray objectsAtIndexes:]` returns an object with `NSArray` type however your `myArray` is `NSMutableArray` type. You should convert the result to `NSMutableArray` before assignment:

```
myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[array objectsAtIndexes:indexSet]];
```

or

```
myArray = [[array objectsAtIndexes:indexSet] mutableCopy];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The code in my question(mentioned above) is inside a 'if' statement which runs when 'array.count >10' else 'myArray' will have the mutablecopy of 'array'. Xcode doesn't show any error but while running the app, when number of objects  in 'array' is greater then 10 (i.e when if statement is executed), 'myArray' has got 0 objects and the app crashes. Why is 'myArray' unable to copy the last ten objects of 'array'?